# Google Search Console most blog posts are marked as: "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical" Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, google-search-console, nuxtjs

i'm using Nuxt JS and the Nuxt JS content module. I'm using the latest version of Nuxt JS and have been creating content, blog posts.

I've got my blog post structure URLs as: `/blog/post-name` and have the Search Console set up.

Oddly, for some reason, the majority of my content is being shown as "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical" by Google and I'm not sure how to fix this in Nuxt JS? Or if there's actually anything wrong at all?

My Nuxt JS config file is:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
import axios from 'axios'
import getRoutes from './utils/getRoutes'

export default {
  /*
  ** Nuxt rendering mode
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode
  */
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Nuxt target
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
  */
  target: 'static',
  /*
  ** Env variables
  */
  env: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL || "https://domain-monitor.io",
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL || "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    ONESIGNAL_PUSH_APP_ID: process.env.ONESIGNAL_PUSH_APP_ID || "",
    ONESIGNAL_SAFARI_WEB_ID: process.env.ONESIGNAL_SAFARI_WEB_ID || "",
    GA_ID: process.env.GA_ID || ""
  },
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
  */
  head: {
    title: 'Domain Monitor',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'og:title', name: 'og:title', content: 'Domain Monitor' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Keep track of your expiring domains today for FREE with our FREE domain monitoring product.' },
      { hid: 'og:description', name: 'og:description', content: 'Keep track of your expiring domains today for FREE with our FREE domain monitoring product.' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/domain-monitor.scss'
  ],
  /*
  ** Bootstrap Vue
  */
  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    bootstrapVueCSS: false
  },
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  ** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
  */
  plugins: [
    { mode: 'client', src: '@/plugins/bootstrap-vue-icons' },
    { mode: 'client', src: '@/plugins/vue-axios' },
    { mode: 'client', src: '@/plugins/vee-validate' },
    { mode: 'client', src: '@/plugins/vue-moment' },
    { mode: 'client', src: '@/plugins/content-images' },
    { mode: 'client', src: '@/plugins/content-videos' }
  ],
  /*
  ** Auto import components
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components
  */
  components: true,
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/google-analytics', {
      id: process.env.GA_ID
    }]
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    '@nuxtjs/onesignal',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxt/content',
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
    ['@nuxtjs/component-cache', { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 5 }] // 5 minutes
  ],
  /*
  ** Auth config
  */
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/account/login',
      logout: '/account/login',
      callback: '/account/login',
      home: '/account/domains'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        login: { url: 'auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
        logout: { url: 'account/logout', method: 'post' },
        user: { url: 'auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'user' }
      }
    }
  },
  /*
  ** One Signal
  */
  oneSignal: {
    init: {
      appId: process.env.ONESIGNAL_PUSH_APP_ID,
      safari_web_id: process.env.ONESIGNAL_SAFARI_WEB_ID,
      allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
      welcomeNotification: {
          disable: true
      }
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
  */
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,

    extend (config, ctx) {
      const vueLoader = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.loader === 'vue-loader')
      vueLoader.options.transformAssetUrls = {
        video: ['src', 'poster'],
        source: 'src',
        img: 'src',
        image: 'xlink:href',
        'b-img': 'src',
        'b-img-lazy': ['src', 'blank-src'],
        'b-card': 'img-src',
        'b-card-img': 'img-src',
        'b-card-img-lazy': ['src', 'blank-src'],
        'b-carousel-slide': 'img-src',
        'b-embed': 'src'
      }
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Sitemap configuration
  ** See https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/sitemap#setup
  */
  sitemap: {
    hostname: process.env.BASE_URL, // https://www.yoursite.com
    exclude: [
      '/account/recovery',
      '/account/reset',
      '/account/profile',
      '/account/domains/add',
      '/account/domains',
      '/account/monitors/add',
      '/account/monitors',
      '/help/account/introduction',
      '/help/monitors/introduction',
      '/help/domains/introduction'
    ],
    routes() {
      return getRoutes();
    },
  }
}
```

And here's a screenshot of what Google Search Console is telling me about one of these pages.

[image: content]

I'm not sure why all of my posts are appearing under this and whether I should be concerned? I haven't long launched the website, and recently have been posting every day.

See: https://domain-monitor.io/blog for the content